# Django: Module not found

Tags: python, django, selenium

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and have Django with Apache in use. There I would like to include a Selenium script. The problem also occurs with other external libraries (for example ics) that are installed via pip, but not all (for example scrapy).

The bash command works correctly.

```
sudo scrapy runspider -s LOG_ENABLED=False -a category=electronics -a domain=system /home/chef/Desktop/synology/selenium/ginger.py > /home/chef/Desktop/synology/selenium/output.txt 2>> /home/chef/Desktop/synology/selenium/output.txt
```

The integration via Django (via another directory) provides:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'selenium'
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.111.174/
Django Version:     2.1.2
Exception Type:     ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'selenium'

Exception Location:     /home/chef/Desktop/Immo/Immo/Immo/ginger.py in <module>, line 1
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.7
Python Path:    

['/usr/bin/python3',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/chef/Desktop/Immo/Immo']
```

The script starts with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from scrapy.http import Request
import time
```

The command line works:

```
chef@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Immo/Immo/Immo$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
chef@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Immo/Immo/Immo$ cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf |egrep WSGI
WSGIPythonPath /usr/bin/python3
chef@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Immo/Immo/Immo$ python3 -m pip search selenium  | egrep -B1 'INSTALLED|LATEST'
selenium (3.141.0)                       - Python bindings for Selenium
  INSTALLED: 3.141.0 (latest)
chef@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Immo/Immo/Immo$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ics import Calendar, Event
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
```

I tried in the console:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

I tried in the wsgi.py:

```
path='/home/chef/Desktop/Immo/Immo'
if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)
        sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6')
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: Have you ran `pip install selenium`?

Comment: I've installed selenium like django:
 pip3 install django==2.1.2
 pip3 install selenium

Comment: Surprisingly, he seems to find scrapy when changing the order of imports

Comment: Result: sudo -H pip3 install selenium